# Video seekbar color change based on forward time

Tags: angularjs, html, css, html5-video

I am trying to work on html5 video where I have to get a white colored line that changes based on where the cursor is hovering on the time bar. This is not to be confused with the current play time which is red colored line. 
How do I get this white line? Do I need to calculate the current play time and forward time and then apply some sort of css on the remaining portion?
Please help me with ideas. Please see the pic to know what I am talking about.

[image]